# escape_javascript not working properly in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems with unobtrusive javascript.  In my `TwitterAccountController` I have:

```
def unshare
  @twitter_account = TwitterAccount.find(params[:id])
  #@twitter_account.update_attribute(:message_enabled, true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @twitter_account.user }
    format.js  # responds to TwitterAccount/share.js.erb
  end
end
```

which is what happens when you click a button in my view named "unshare"

the unshare.js.erb that responds is:

```
var div_name = '<%="div#share_form_#{@twitter_account.id}"%>'
$(div_name).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/share', :locals => {:twitter_account    => @twitter_account}))%>");
```

It's suppose to switch the button from "unshare" button to "share" button.  But when the "unshare" button is clicked, this is the code generated from escape_javascript:

```
<form accept-charset=UTF-8 action=/twitter_accounts/1/share data-remote=true method=get>
  <div style=margin:0;padding:0;display:inline><input name=utf8 type=hidden value=&#x2713; />
  div>        
  <input name=commit type=submit value=share />
form>
```

you can tell the closing tags are messed up, does anyone know the reason for this???

my javascript_include_tag is:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min.js', "rails.js", "d3.js","d3.time.js", "raphael.js", "collapse_menu.js" %>
```

the share partial:

```
<%= form_tag(share_twitter_account_path(twitter_account), :method => 'get', :remote => true) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "share"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I assume the partial itself is good?

Comment: partial is good.  it's been tested without javascript already.  what quotes am i missing?

Comment: i added the share partial.  im still unclear what attributes values is to be quoted.

Comment: What's the real response from the server? I mean, not the HTML generated, but the JS it will execute...

Comment: okay after researching i figured it out.  I'm on rails 3.0.8 and there was a bug with escape_javascript.  Updated rails and it worked fine.  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment i figured it out. I'm on rails 3.0.8 and there was a bug with escape_javascript. Updated rails and it worked fine. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem and simply changed

```
$(div_name).html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'shared/share', :locals => {:twitter_account    => @twitter_account}))%>");
```

for

```
$(div_name).html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "shared/share", :locals => {:twitter_account    => @twitter_account}))%>');
```

which is just inverting the way you single/double quote. Worth a try :)